# Android 4.0+ list selector on item long click - Need to be persistent - Not working

Tags: android, listview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have seen many posts on this issue but none of them seem to work. So here goes.

I am testing my Android app in ICS / JB . I have a list of items and on long click of an item on that list , I am displaying a contextual action bar.

The list selector is lost once the action bar pops up. I would like it stay persistent as long as the action bar stays.

I used the selectors . 1 for list selector and another for list item selector. I have also experimented with activated state.

The only one that finally sort of worked was when I manually change background on item click listener. But then it becomes too complicated to track what item is selected and what item is not and resetting them as per their state.

Is there a straight forward way for the list item to be highlighted when a action in performed in its context.

Please advise. I am going nuts with this issue.

In response to Al: In one of those permutations , the selection does show up but does not go away .

If I close the contextual action bar or select a menu item in the bar it stays. If I select the same item again it stays.

The only way is to click another item in the list and the selection shifts to the new item.

Item selection:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
           <item 
    android:state_selected="true" 
    android:drawable="@android:color/black" />
            <item 
    android:state_activated="true" 
    android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />  
           <item 
    android:state_activated="true" android:state_focused="false"
    android:drawable="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />   
           <item 
    android:state_focused="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/selectedrow" />
      <item 
    android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
       <item android:state_focused="false"
    android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_radio" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Are you setting android:choiceMode? By default lists do not allow a selection.
See the documentation on [AbsListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:choiceMode) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If your selector is set up properly setting the view received on the onItemLongClick to selected should do it

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    arg1.setSelected(true);
    return true;
}
```